# How do I document the types of an external react component

Tags: typescript

I am trying to document the types of a library in a `global.d.ts` in my project.

I can't figure out how to specify that the default export should be a react component with such and such props.

I found a mention about `ComponentClass`, but no information about it.

I imagine it should be something like:

```
declare module 'yes-exporting-component' {
  const PieChart: <{
    data: { color: string, value: any }[]
  }>;
  export default PieChart;
}
```

Obviously the syntax above is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do it like this:

```
declare module 'yes-exporting-component'
{
    export interface MyPropType
    {
        data: { color: string, value: any }[];
    }

    class PieChart extends React.Component<MyPropType, any>
    {

    }

    export default PieChart;
}
```

Comment: Can you add explanation why is that valid syntax?

Comment: That is how you export something in typescript. You cant really export something using JXS/TSX specific "syntax sugar": <SomeElement .../> as it is effectively gets compiled to React.createElement - and that returns an object and not a class as you want it to.